Vuforia License Error in Unity when building for android

I keep getting the above error.
Invalid AssetDatabase path: C:/Users/GU502/Desktop/Unity Proj/IndoorNav v3/Assets\VuforiaLicense.cs. Use path relative to the project folder.
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
Vuforia.EditorClasses.LicenseKeyObfuscationTask:Execute ()
BuildObserver/<>c:<OnPreprocessBuild>b__3_0 (Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask)
System.Collections.Generic.List1<Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask>:ForEach (System.Action1<Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask>)
BuildObserver:OnPreprocessBuild (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

I got it when I built my project for android.
I want to know I this issue prevents the apk from work, I just want to test
and also i don't see the VuforiaLiscence.cs anywhere in my project

Could you share a error message with screenshots?

I added a screenshot to the original post

So, I started a new project just to check.
I don't get this error when I'm yet to put a vuforia license key in the vuforia config.
whenever I put one and build I get the error.

Could you remove the space at path?
It should be has no space with path, i think.
